# client to screen and setcursorpos to firemonkey

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I am Trying to convert some code from delphi to firemoneky but come across something i am unsure how to do in firemoneky.
 `SetCursorpos`

```
  setcursorpos(p.x,p.y);
```

Any idea on how to do this in firemonkey?

i have tried `game.SetCursor(p.x,p.y);`
but it doe not like it says setcursor is undefined.. Also did add fmx.plateform to my uses list.

Comment: Weird, there's `Platform.GetMousePos`, but 'SetMousePos' is nowhere to be seen..

Comment: there is a platform.setcursor but not sure why it did not take. Also tried getmousepos just to see if that worked and it will not either.. I assume the unit is fmx.plateform?  and game is the name of the forum

Comment: If not exist you can wrote your own using the [CGWarpMouseCursorPosition](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGWarpMouseCursorPosition) method in OSX and [SetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows.

Comment: Search the FMX source for a call to SetCursorPos. If one exists, odds are it's in the function you need to call. Otherwise you'll need to call SetCursorPos in your code. If your app is x-plat, wrap it up as RRUZ says. If not, just go ahead and call it.

Comment: Should SetCursor not work? I would think it would, but I am setting it up wrong?

Comment: @Glen - SetCursor is for changing the cursor. Arrow, hourglass etc..

Answer (score 1):

There is no call to the `SetCursorPos` Win32 API function in the XE2 FMX source code. From which I conclude that nothing in the FMX framework encapsulates that functionality.

You'll need to call `SetCursorPos` directly in your Windows FMX projects. If you are targeting other platforms then you'll need to call the appropriate API for that platform.

Comment: Then the final sentence applies.

Comment: thanks for the help, i am not sure how to do that, but at least i have a direction.  Still going to wait for an example or more details on how to do this before accepting answers

Comment: You should not hope for an answer with iOS detail because the question is not about iOS. The question is a platform independent question about FMX. If you are interested in platform specific iOS details you should ask about that. Finally, ask yourself what cursor position means on iOS? Have you even seen your iPhone display a cursor?

Comment: FMX should be multiplatform, i only said ios cause you brought up targeting a single platform.  I assume cursor position in fmx would be the same as any?  where to start when typeing?

Comment: FMX can only abstract concepts that are common to all platforms. Cursor pos is **not** where text appears when typing. Only meaningful on systems with mouse/cursor. Have you ever seen a cursor on an iPhone?

Comment: yes, when you have text and you try to insert a char within that text, you get a cursor

Comment: That's the caret. The cursor is different. On a desktop machine, move your mouse around. The thing that moves is the cursor. Now find an edit control and type text. The vertical bar that marks the insertion point is the caret. Note that he caret is independent from the cursor.

Comment: a cursor is an indicator used to show the position on a computer monitor or other display device that will respond to input from a text input or pointing device.  flashing text cursor is sometimes called caret and mouse cursor sometimes called pointer...but both are cursors.

Comment: In the original program, which I assume is a VCL program, what is `SetCursorPos`. My assumption is that it is this function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394.aspx  Is my assumption incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I found something, but it works only with windows:
- You need to make a DATAmodule
- Set the type of it to VCL (This is possible for me because i'm using delphi XE 10.1)
- Add the Windows unit to the uses
- Make a procedure in the DataModul like this

```
`procedure TMouseController.SetCursorPosition(x, y: integer);`
begin
  SetCursorPos(x, y);
end;

end.
```

-And then use this in the program like this:

```
`procedure TMainForm.Form3DShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  Center: TPoint;
begin
  Center.SetLocation(Screen.Width div 2, Screen.Height div 2);
  MouseController.SetCursorPosition(Center.X, Center.Y);
end;`
```